# Reset Button in twitter bootstrap not working in django form

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the twitter bootstrap reset button like this

```
<input class="btn btn-danger" type="reset" value="Reset">
```

It works when i first load the form via django formView

But once i get the error in submission and i get the form back with data then reset form is not working. Is that ok or i have the problem

Comment: Wow, I haven't seen a reset button on a form since about 1996.

Comment: @DanielRoseman i did not understand what u mean by that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because when the form is reloaded with the errors, 
django adds value="some value" to your text inputs or seleced to select or checked to checkboxes 
what reset does is reset to the default value not clearing the texboxes or inputs

```
<form>
<input type="text" value="asd">
<input  type="reset">
</form>
```

here when the text box is edited and clicked reset, the text input will reset to value 'asd'